# Hosting Provider Hosted App on SharePoint Application Server in a 3 tier farm

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, provider-hosted-app

We are planning to host a provider hosted app on a SharePoint Application server in a 3 tier architecture. Assuming that my host web would be in SharePoint web server and app web would be in application server.

My question is if I host this provider hosted app in same farm on application server would it have impact on performance, if yes then how?